# upgrading hibernate causes servlet-api-2.5.jar error in eclipse maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, servlets

Can someone show me how to make other adjustments so that I can successfully upgrade to the new  hibernate version in my eclipse maven project?  I changed the Hibernate version to 4.2.6.Final by changing the following in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

However, now the Markers tab in the eclipse project contains the following error listings:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unknown tag (form:label).   documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 21 JSP Problem
Unknown tag (form:input).   documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 18 JSP Problem
Unknown tag (form:label).   documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 25 JSP Problem
Unknown tag (form:textarea).    documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 22 JSP Problem
Unknown tag (form:form).    documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 13 JSP Problem
Unknown tag (form:label).   documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 17 JSP Problem
Unknown tag (form:errors).  documents.jsp   /DocumentManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp    line 14 JSP Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    DocumentManager     Unknown Java Problem
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\mypath\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar' DocumentManager     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I checked and 'D:\mypath.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar' is indeed present in my computer.  I also forced an additional maven update just to be safe, and it produces the same list in the Markers tab.

For reference, my pom.xml file is included as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- dependency to fix JSPServletException -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.32</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>               
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <groupId>DocumentManager</groupId>
  <artifactId>DocumentManager</artifactId>
</project>
```

### EDIT/ANSWER:

The solution involved changing the jstl tag and upgrading hibernate as follows:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>  
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.2</version>  
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that javax.servlet was replaced with jstl, as per the answerer's suggestion in a comment below.  However, the version number 1.1.2 is also the same for both the jstl and the taglibs nodes.

I am marking an accepted answer below because the answerer wrote something close to this in a comment below his answer, even though the code in his answer itself was not ultimately the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `servlet-api` in `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. Did you notice that the dependency of servlet-api 2.5 was already in the pom.xml in my original posting above? Out of due diligence to your suggestion, I added the scope provided tag from your suggestion and then forced an update of maven, which got rid of the unknown tag errors.  However, the non-existant library error for servlet-api 2.5 is still in the markers tab of my project, despite using your explicit code.  Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: can you try chaning the jstl dependency to <dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency> and why you need the last jsp-api dependency?

Comment: Thank you again.  I tried your suggestions and added an edit to my original posting above with the results.  The jsp-api dependency eliminated a previous problem of tomcat not starting.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The reference I am using for the syntax of the jstl dependency comes from the link at the end of this comment(I upgraded to 1.2 while I was confirming the syntax). Using the syntax in the link just leaves my original servlet-api-2.5 non-existant error.  Do you have any more suggestions?   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Comment: The taglib errors went away when I changed the jstl dependency in pom.xml to the syntax from mvnrepository.com that I posted in the comment immediately preceding this above.  Is there any documentation indicating we should not use this syntax?  However, to answer your question, here is the <@taglib from jsp which formerly had an error:  <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"  prefix="spring"%>

Comment: I added a second edit to my original posting above to reflect what is currently on my machine.

Comment: Do an mvn clean and try build again!

Comment: I am going to mark this as answered because the original problem seems to be resolved, and the new error messages may be off topic now.  If working on the new errors causes this problem to resurface, I will reply here again.  Thank you.

Comment: Note the EDIT/ANSWER that I added at the bottom of my original posting above. Thank you for helping me get on the right track.